# How To Simply Push A Variable To An HtmlService Template AS Html

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am using:

```
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("MyForm.html");
```

Which contains a variable:

```
<?= defaultInnerHtml ?>
```

And I am trying to assign THIS variable with the content of another HTML file:

```
template.defaultInnerHtml
    = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(
        "MyInnerHtml.html").getContent();
```

But the contents of MyInnerHtml.html become encoded: the angle brackets are replaced with entities etc. I am trying just to stuff some more Html inside the MyForm.html file before serving that back.

I can't see how to get just the raw contents to show up in place of the variable in the template.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable this *contextual escaping* of special characters, change your template so it embeds the value of the variable like this:

```
<?!= defaultInnerHtml ?>
```

Note the exclamation mark. This specifies force-printing, which directs the template engine to embed the contents of the variable verbatim.

From [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets):

> Contextual escaping is important if your script allows untrusted user input. By contrast, you’ll need to force-print if your scriptlet’s output intentionally contains HTML or scripts that you want to insert exactly as specified.